# How to make Views with an Invisible attribute 'Visible' after clicking a button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, visibility

I have several Views, text views, and a button that have the android:visibility="invisible" attribute. My goal is to click a button that resides above these 'invisible' widgets, so that these widgets will become visible. I created another java class called 'VisibilityActivity.java" and tried the following method. But for some reason when I run the app, the button doesn't do anything. I don't know what I'm missing.

Here's the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class VisibilityActivity extends Activity {

    private View mVictim;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_property3);

        mVictim = findViewById(R.id.horizontalRule1);
        mVictim = findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
        mVictim = findViewById(R.id.horizontalRule2);

        Button submitRating = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitRatingButton);

        submitRating.setOnClickListener(mVisibleListener);

    }

    OnClickListener mVisibleListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mVictim.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    };

}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/custom_background"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/ratingsInfo"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/black1" />

    <View 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@color/black1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="@string/yourRating"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/black1" />

    <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/submitRatingButton"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:text="@string/submitRating"
    android:textColor="@color/black1" />


    <View 
    android:id="@+id/horizontalRule1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@color/black1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/summaryInfo"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/black1"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

    <View 
    android:id="@+id/horizontalRule2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@color/black1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="@string/ourRating"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/black1"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

    <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:stepSize=".01"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="@string/overallRating"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/black1"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

    <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar3"
    android:color="@color/black1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:stepSize=".01"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/saveContinueButton3"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:text="@string/saveContinue"
    android:textColor="@color/black1"
    android:onClick="onSaveAndContinue3Clicked"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am updating **user936414**'s answer.

```
OnClickListener mVisibleListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if( mText.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE )
            mText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            mText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if( mRule1.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE )
            mRule1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            mRule1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if( mRule2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE )
            mRule2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            mRule2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
};
```

Also you might want to experiment with View.GONE.

Comment: I tried this too, but no luck :( I think the problem has something to do with the button. When I click it nothing happens. Not sure what the problem is...

Comment: Can you put a log and check if your listener is being called when u click the button?

Comment: Nothing seems to be unusual. Logcat doesn't pick up anything when I press the button. Could it possibly be a problem with the class? Should I not be using an Activity?

Comment: ok now a very basic question, the xml that you have provided, is that the same xml as what you have set with setContentView(R.layout.new_property3)? ie, is the xml provided above called new_property3?

Comment: Well the class looks fine, it seems that when you start this activity, the screen will contain the view provided by ure xml and you should be able to click on the button and register. Can you provide the whole class? just to make sure something else is not overriding whats there in the code above.

Comment: That is the whole class, but not the main one. I created that class by clicking File > New > Class, then going from there. Should I not do that? Should I put it in the original class instead?

Comment: Hold on. I am not clear here. Where are you calling this class from? Can you put the code snippet where you are calling this Activity?

Comment: Oh I think that is the problem. I haven't called this Activity. What would be the code to do that?

Comment: Do one thing all that we have discussed here, put it in your main activity. It will work.

Comment: Ok, I did that. One more question though, do I still define it as a 'public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)'?

Comment: Put all of this code in your onCreate method of your mainActivity. Put it up if you are having any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
findViewById(R.id.ratingBar3).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.saveContinueButton3).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

you made it invisible view invisible again.. try the above code

Comment: Yeah that's because I was trying it the other way around to see if that worked. Sorry about that. But still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public class VisibilityActivity extends Activity {

private TextView mText;
private View mRule1, mRule2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_property3);

    mText= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.horizontalRule1);
    mRule1 = findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
    mRule2 = findViewById(R.id.horizontalRule2);

    Button submitRating = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitRatingButton);

    submitRating.setOnClickListener(mVisibleListener);

}

OnClickListener mVisibleListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRule1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRule2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};

}
```

Comment: Still nothing. I think it has something to do with the onClickListener or something. It still does absolutely nothing when I click the button.

Answer (score -1):

```
Button submitRating = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitRatingButton);
        submitRating.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener)
        {
             @Override
         public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                              //Insert your code here
                    }
        }
```

Comment: This is an old question that seems to have already been resolved. It's also not very clear what your answer adds; OP already had this boilerplate code before asking.